# Variable in select in active record in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple active record query.

```
Product.active.select('stats_date, clicks_through')
```

I want to make clicks_through as a variable that will contain name of the attribute.

I tried

```
.select('stats_date, #{type_of_data}')
```

But this is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: What error are you receiving? I assume this code is in your controller? Also, can you post your `Product` model? I'd be interested to see what the `active` class method/scope does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If type_of_data is a variable that holds a string or symbol that is a column in your database, the following should work (assuming that `Product.active` is a scope that returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`).

Just change it to:

```
.select("stats_date, "#{type_of_data}")
```

(note the double quotes, which are required to use string interpolation in Ruby).

Comment: Doesn't string interpolation like this open up an application to sql injection?

Answer (score 0):

It's been almost 10 years, but there are some public methods available for this;

```
User.select(
  User.sanitize_sql_array([':column', column: 'id'])
)
# "SELECT 'id' FROM \"users\"
```

It's basically that, you use the methods that ActiveRecord provides to sanitize the arguments for `select`.

Whether your query is prone to SQLi or not will depend entirely on the implementation of the `sanitize_` methods.